# Can I add adress lines to a Text View from contacts

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Is it possible to add all the lines of an address to a text view, so far I can only get the last line to show up in the view `adresslines`.

```
  self.adresslines.text = (NSString *)(CFDictionaryGetValue(dictionary, kABPersonAddressCityKey));
        self.adresslines.text = (NSString *)(CFDictionaryGetValue(dictionary, kABPersonAddressStreetKey));
        self.adresslines.text = (NSString *) (CFDictionaryGetValue(dictionary, kABPersonAddressZIPKey));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it now you are setting the text view's text with each line of the address. You want to append, not replace. Something like this will work:

```
NSMutableString *text = [NSMutableString string];    
[text appendString:(NSString *)(CFDictionaryGetValue(dictionary, kABPersonAddressCityKey))];
[text appendString:@"\n"];
[text appendString:(NSString *)(CFDictionaryGetValue(dictionary, kABPersonAddressStreetKey))];
[text appendString:@"\n"];
[text appendString:(NSString *) (CFDictionaryGetValue(dictionary, kABPersonAddressZIPKey))];
self.addresslines.text = text;
```

Of course you can add checks in here to avoid blank lines or add other formatting as desired.

Comment: Works a charm! Thank you I can learn off this now, thanks for explaining.